# Using two jquery.js file in a webpage

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I m using two script in my web-page  first one is zoomer second one is  a pop up maker a image when it clicked with a bigger size;

But both the scripts have jquery.js file when I open my  page  everything seems mess,
I gave them different names but it does not work correctly what should I do ?

Comment: Can you specify which versions of jQuery please?

Comment: zoomer script's version for jquery.js is v 1.12.2.3..slider 's version jQuery is JavaScript Library v1.3.

Answer (score 1):

only include the most recent one. then it should work

Comment: not really, depend on which version of jquery that the plugins will support

Comment: the most recent one should do it.

Comment: zoomer script's version for   jquery.js is v 1.12.2.3..slider 's version jQuery is JavaScript Library v1.3.

Comment: use only the v1.3 this should do it